# A JavaScript language problem

Tags: javascript

In the following example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
    var str = '11';
    str = str++;
    alert(str); // 11
</script>
```

why is the result `11` and not `12`?

In this example the result is `12`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
    var str = '11';
    str++;
    alert(str); // 12
</script>
```

Why is this so?

Thank you!

---

```
var str = 10;
var re = str++;
alert(re); // 10
alert(str); // 11
```

`str` will return 10 to `re` first, and then increments `str` itself to 11.

But

```
var str = 10;
var str = str++;
alert(str); // 10
```

In this case, `str` return 10 to `str` first, and then `str` should increments `str` itself to 11.

But it doesn't. Can anyone explain this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because the return value of a post increment (`str++`) is the value **before** incrementing.

Example:

```
var x = 10;
alert(x++); //10, because return value is value before increment
alert(x); //11 because the variable was incremented on the previous line
```

The way to solve this issue is to use the **pre-increment** operator, which is simply the `++` operator ***before*** its operand (`++str`). This will add 1 to the operand and return the **new value** - as opposed to the post-increment operator (`str++`) which will add 1 to operand and return the **old value**.

Example:

```
var x = 10;
alert(++x); //11
```

By the way, the statement `str = str++` is a **real gotcha**. The reason why:

The expression `str++` returns the original value, so when you reassign it to `str`, you are essentially re-assigning the **OLD VALUE** back into `str`. Hence zero mutation to the variable and **you are back at square one**.

Here's how your code should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
    var str = '11';
    alert(++str); // 12
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And can you explain this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790200/a-javascript-language-problem/4790850#4790850)?

Answer (score 1):

The expression with the `++` operator first evaluates to 11 and then increments the value of `str`.

Try `++str`. It will return 12.

Comment: And then - don't forget - assigns the pre-increment value, after incrementing, so you end up right back where you started! :)